# I'm using prototype.js to pass POST content to a php script but FILE POST doesn't go

Tags: javascript, post, prototypejs

I'm using this script to pass my POST contents :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
// <![CDATA[  
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {  

    function sendForm(event){  
        // we stop the default submit behaviour  
        Event.stop(event);  
        var oOptions = {  
            method: "POST",  
            parameters: Form.serialize("standardform"),  
            asynchronous: true,  
            onFailure: function (oXHR) {  
                $('feedback').update(oXHR.statusText);  
            },  
            onLoading: function (oXHR) {  
            $('feedback').update('Enregistrement en cours ... <img src="images/throbber.gif" title="Loading..." alt="Enregistrement..." border="0" />');  
            },                            
            onSuccess: function(oXHR) {  
               $('feedback').update(oXHR.responseText);  
            }                 
        };  
        var oRequest = new Ajax.Updater({success: oOptions.onSuccess.bindAsEventListener(oOptions)}, "enregistre-site-marque.php", oOptions);             
    }  
    Event.observe('submitButton', 'click', sendForm, false);              
});   
// ]]>
```

But my FILE POST doesn't pass, they are empty in my `enregistre-site-marque.php` script.
How can I pass POST content?

Answer (score 0):

Prototype.js:  Form.serialize()

"Also, file inputs are skipped as they cannot be serialized and sent using only JavaScript."

see:  http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Form/serialize/

Sounds like you can't AJAX the file this way -- try doing it with a regular form-post, or (if necessary) using a Javascript/ AJAX uploader.

Simple HTML form submit, without AJAX, would probably be the technically simplest & most reliable (thus preferable) solution -- if you can do that.

Comment: **IF** you can limit your user base to just browsers that support the HTML5 File API you can post the file using `Ajax.Request()` but only in that instance - otherwise you need to use another method suggested by Thomas W